# Finding discount % given original price and discount value?

Tags: percentages

I want to know given the `original price` and `discount value` how can i find the discount percentage e.g

```
SUB-TOTAL:  $209,055.00
One -Time Special Discount  : -$38,000.00
Grand Total :   $171,055.00
```

Comment: Use `Discount/Original Price x 100%` to compute the discount in %

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime you are talking about discounted prices you can use the following equations to find either the original amount, new price, discount amount, or discount percentage:

equation 1: original amount - discount amount = new amount
equation 2: discount amount = (original amount) * ( the decimal form of percent discount)

Since we know the discount amount and the original amount then we can use equation 2 to solve for the decimal form of the percent discount. You can then change this into a percentage by moving the decimal place two to the left (same as multiplying by 100).